# FileSaver.js displays file contents in browser

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js

I use FileSaver.js (from within GWT) to save a generated HTML file to the client.
This works without a problem with 95% of our customers.

But with some (the webapp is installed on a IIS server with the client) this is not working in Chrome and Firefox (but it does work in IE).

In Chrome the effect is that the website url changes to an url like filesystem:https://www.abc.be/temporary/saved/filename.html.download and in the browser window you just see the contents of the file (you just see the html code, not rendered).

In Firefox the effects is almost the same. Except in this case the url looks like blob:https://247.abc.be/7bec1d6a-a39f-49eb-ab86-835011b502d6

Any idea what is going wrong on these specific installs ?

This is the GWT JSNI method I use to call FileSaver. Working almost in every case.

```
/**
 * Save text to filename.
 * @param fileName The filename to use
 * @param text The text to save
 */
public static native void saveText(String fileName, String text)
/*-{
   var textMessage = new Blob([text],{type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
   $wnd.saveAs(textMessage, fileName);
}-*/;
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? The js that interacts with FileSaver? Does it only happen when deployed on the IIS server or does it also appear on a local deployment?

Comment: I just call the saveAs message from FileSaver with a fileName and a string that has to be saved. This works on local deployment, and on 95% of the IIS installations. Every customers configures his own IIS, and it is only with some customers that this problem arrises. The string is just displayed in the browser and no file is saved. Also some strange URL that starts with filesystem: or blob: depending on the browser is displayed. I added the jsni method to the initial question.